# Why does my Android app keep showing 'com.sekinchan.travel.mainactivity' text?

Tags: android-activity

[image]

Anyone can tell why my android app keep appear this texts “com.sekinchan.travel.mainactivity” on every screen

Trying to modify the adroidmanifest.xml but unfortunately cannot figure out what is wrong